# Need to select only the Unique value from xsl

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, ibm-datapower

Input XML with Multiple same key value:

```
<ns2:enumCollection>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>001</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>                             
</ns2:enumCollection>
```

Expected Output Result

```
<ns2:enumCollection>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>001</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>                             
</ns2:enumCollection>
```

Need Help on this Transformation.
I am trying to use xsl:Key function but not able to transform successfully.

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you have currently tried? Thanks!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="element-key" match="/enumCollection/*" use="name()" />

  <xsl:template match="/enumCollection">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="">
        <xsl:copy-of select="(./item/key | following-sibling::*[name() = name(current())])" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: not working in case of multiple scenarios

Comment: Are you trying to group `ns3:item` elements by their `ns3:key`'s value?

Comment: yes only want to keep the ns3:item groups with unique values of the ns3:key

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT, as it is very hard to read code samples in comments. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to campare with preceding-sibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that your input XML has namespace prefixes, but there are no declarations for them, which is not allowed. I am assuming your actual XML does have them though! For the purposes of this answer though, I am going to make up some namespaces

```
<ns2:enumCollection xmlns:ns2="ns2" xmlns:ns3="ns3">
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>001</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>                             
</ns2:enumCollection>
```

To get unique values, you can make use of a technique called Muenchian grouping as that involves getting the unique values initially, but in your case you are discarding the rest of the 'group'.

If you are grouping `items` by `key`, then your XML should actually look like this

```
<xsl:key name="element-key" match="ns3:item" use="ns3:key" />
```

Then, to get your "distinct" values, you would do this to get the `item` for the first occurrence of each `key`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="ns2" xmlns:ns3="ns3">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="element-key" match="ns3:item" use="ns3:key" /> 

    <xsl:template match="ns2:enumCollection">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ns3:item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('element-key', ns3:key)[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternatively, you could have a template to 'discard' the elements that aren't first in each group

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="ns2" xmlns:ns3="ns3">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="element-key" match="ns3:item" use="ns3:key" /> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns3:item[generate-id() != generate-id(key('element-key', ns3:key)[1])]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both of these output the following

```
<ns2:enumCollection xmlns:ns2="ns2" xmlns:ns3="ns3">
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>
    <ns3:item>
        <ns3:key>001</ns3:key>
        <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
    </ns3:item>
</ns2:enumCollection>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, need one more help if we want to keep the items with unique combination of key and value, how can we achive it

Comment: You can do something like `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('element-key', ns3:key)" />` to get all the items in the group with the same key. But it's probably best to ask a whole new question about this, as it will be hard to give a precise answer using just comments. Thanks!

Comment: if you can add comments to the below post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442729/remove-the-duplicate-node-based-on-unique-combination-in-xslt

Comment: Sorry, I initially misunderstood what you were asking. It is actually quite straight-forward to group on key and value. I've answered your new question to show this.