# Remove the duplicate node based on unique combination in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Input XML with Multiple same key value:

```
                    <ns2:enumCollection xmlns:ns2="ns2" xmlns:ns3="ns3">
                        <ns3:item>
                            <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
                            <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
                        </ns3:item>
                        <ns3:item>
                            <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
                            <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
                        </ns3:item>
                        <ns3:item>
                            <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
                            <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
                        </ns3:item>
                        <ns3:item>
                            <ns3:key>001</ns3:key>
                            <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
                        </ns3:item>                             
                    </ns2:enumCollection>
```

Expected Output Result:

```
                    <ns2:enumCollection>
                        <ns3:item>
                            <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
                            <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA1</ns3:value>
                        </ns3:item>
                        <ns3:item>
                            <ns3:key>000</ns3:key>
                            <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
                        </ns3:item>
                        <ns3:item>
                            <ns3:key>001</ns3:key>
                            <ns3:value>GRS Tracker00CA2</ns3:value>
                        </ns3:item>                             
                    </ns2:enumCollection>
```

Need Help on this Transformation.  Node with unique combination of  and  has to kept.

Comment: @S Ray, post u r tried XSLT, as well as XSLT version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a concatenated key here

```
<xsl:key name="element-key" match="ns3:item" use="concat(ns3:key, '|', ns3:value)" />
```

Then you can get the distinct elements like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ns3:item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('element-key', concat(ns3:key, '|', ns3:value))[1])]"/>
```

The main point to make is that the delimiter used (`|` in this case) should not appear in either of the `key` or `value` values.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="ns2" xmlns:ns3="ns3">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="element-key" match="ns3:item" use="concat(ns3:key, '|', ns3:value)" /> 

    <xsl:template match="ns2:enumCollection">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="ns3:item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('element-key', concat(ns3:key, '|', ns3:value))[1])]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim for the help.

Comment: For future reference, can you make sure you include in your question any XSLT code samples you have tried. For example, including the sample that grouped on just the key. It does make the question easier to answer, and benefits other people who read the question too. Thank you!